# First Git Push Rejected

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

When i type `git push origin master` the following error message is shown from git:

```
To https://github.com/farrasdoko/RumahSakit.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/farrasdoko/RumahSakit.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then, i type `git fetch origin` , `git merge origin master` & `git pull origin master`
the following error message is shown from git:

```
From https://github.com/farrasdoko/RumahSakit
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How to push it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Often when that happens, what you'd really like to do is to add the additional commits in `origin/master` into your branch *before* your own commits. **You can use the `rebase` command** to do that:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

That will pull the new commits from `origin` into your branch and then add your own new commits on top, so that your commits are the latest. You may encounter some conflicts while rebasing. When that happens, `git` will stop and tell you to resolve the conflicts; after that, you should `git add` the affected files and then `git rebase --continue`. Or, if you decide you don't know how to deal with the problem, you can `git rebase --abort` and your branch will be returned to the same state it was in before the `git rebase` command started.

`git rebase` is a powerful command that can make a quick mess of your branch, so be careful with it, but don't be afraid of it. Standard computing advice applies: back up your work before doing anything if you're not confident. Luckily, it's easy to just make a new branch as a backup (`git checkout -b my_backup_branch`) and then switch back to your working branch.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches. I assume you are already checked out to master.

1.

```
git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Resolve conflict, then

```
git add -A .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push origin master
```

**OR**
2.

```
git pull -f origin master     //The -f flag stands for force
```